# How to get the z-index attribute of an element using Selenium through Python?

Tags: python, css, selenium, z-index, webdriverwait

I have been told that I can check the "z-index" attribute of web elements to check the depth of them. 
I first used one of the following two statements to locate the element successfully.

```
e = WebDriverWait(tA.driver,1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xPath)))
e = WebDriverWait(tA.driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xPath)))
```

Then I used the following python code with firefox and win10:

```
zi = e.value_of_css_property("z-index")
```

The webpage URL is https://irs.thsrc.com.tw/IMINT/ which has a pop-up message box.

I supposed that the z-index of this box should be one and the other elements should be zero. However, using the above python statement makes Selenium returned "auto" to all my queries. 
I read some people suggested that z-index query does not work for element with position value "static". 
So in the following page: http://aludratest.github.io/aludratest/xref/org/aludratest/service/gui/web/selenium/selenium2/ZIndexSupport.html
repeated query to the "z-index" property is done until it is not "auto".
But I tried this and it results in locating failure after a few trials.

My questions are the following:

1. Can I change the position property of the element in this case ?
2. Will it work if I change the position property of the element ?

Thanks

Comment: `z-index` for which element?

Comment: Hi, dear:  I need collect the z-indices of all actionable elements and then compare their z-indices to see which are on top of the others.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were close. The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all"))).value_of_css_property("z-index"))
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ']"))).value_of_css_property("z-index"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1002
  ```
- Note: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try later and see if this solve my problem.  But I am also using firefox in the experiment.  Will that be possible if you show me how to adapt your solution for firefox.  Or can I just do some simplistic substitution ?

Comment: Hi, dear Debanjan:
I just tried the statement EC.visibility_of_element_located(...) but did not succeed.   I will appreciate if you can explain what those options are for ?  Can I do those options with firefox ?  Thanks

Comment: @FarnWang The options were to make _Chrome_ browser maximized. I have removed them. Now the solution should work cross browser.

Comment: I tried and no luck.  firefox and webdriver always returned 'auto'.  Maybe it is because of firefox.  I will try tomorrow and report to you.  Thanks for your kind patience.

Comment: Hi, dear Debanjan: I also tried Chrome and somehow the returned values are all "auto" either. 
I also imported the three modules that you requested.  But still no luck.   For Chrome the answers are still "auto".   Could it be win10 ?  Or python ?